# Store int to and retrieve from char array

Tags: c, buffer, printf, scanf

What I'm gonna do is to store two integers into a char array, and then get them back from the array. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT_WIDTH       4
#define BUFFER_SIZE     10

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    int input1 = 0, input2 = 0;
    int output1 = 0, output2 = 0;

    printf("int size: %d\n", sizeof(int));

    printf("Please input two integers\n");
    scanf("%d", &input1);
    scanf("%d", &input2);
    printf("The input integers are : %d %d\n", input1, input2);

    snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "%d", input1);
    snprintf(buffer + INT_WIDTH, BUFFER_SIZE - INT_WIDTH, "%d", input2);

    printf("Buffer:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("0x%02x ", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &output1);
    sscanf(buffer + INT_WIDTH, "%d", &output2);

    printf("The output integers retrieved from buffer: %d %d\n", output1, output2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
int size: 4
Please input two integers
100
200
The input integers are : 100 200
Buffer:
0x31 0x30 0x30 0x00 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x00 0x00 0x00
The output integers retrieved from buffer: 100 200
```

It looks fine. But when I input 1000 and 2000 rather than 100 and 200, things go wrong:

```
int size: 4
Please input two integers
1000
2000
The input integers are : 1000 2000
Buffer:
0x31 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x00 0x00
The output integers retrieved from buffer: 10002000 2000
```

Where is wrong in my code?

Similarly, I tried the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE     10

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    int input1 = 0, input2 = 0;
    int output1 = 0, output2 = 0;

    printf("Please input two integers\n");
    scanf("%d", &input1);
    scanf("%d", &input2);
    printf("The input integers are : %d %d\n", input1, input2);

    snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "%4d%4d", input1, input2);

    printf("Buffer:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("0x%02x ", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    sscanf(buffer, "%4d%4d", &output1, &output2);

    printf("The output integers retrieved from buffer: %d %d\n", output1, output2);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Please input two integers
1000
2000
The input integers are : 1000 2000
Buffer:
0x31 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x00 0x00
The output integers retrieved from buffer: 1000 2000

Please input two integers
10000
20000
The input integers are : 10000 20000
Buffer:
0x31 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x00
The output integers retrieved from buffer: 1000 200
```

As you can see, 1000 and 2000 is OK, 10000 and 20000 is wrong.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clifford has pointed out, I was storing character strings of digit characters, not storing binary content of integers. Here's the code that I really want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE     10

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    int input = 0, output = 0;

    printf("size of int: %d\n", sizeof(int));

    printf("Please input an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("The input integer is : %d\n", input);

    memcpy(buffer, &input, sizeof(int));

    printf("Buffer:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) {
            printf("0x%02x ", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    memcpy(&output, buffer, sizeof(int));

    printf("The output integer retrieved from buffer: %d\n", output);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of int: 4
Please input an integer
1024
The input integer is : 1024
Buffer:
0x0 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
The output integer retrieved from buffer: 1024

size of int: 4
Please input an integer
2147483647      (2 ^ 31 - 1)
The input integer is : 2147483647
Buffer:
0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0x7f 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
The output integer retrieved from buffer: 2147483647

size of int: 4
Please input an integer
2147483648      (2 ^ 31)
The input integer is : -2147483648
Buffer:
0x0 0x0 0x0 0xffffff80 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
The output integer retrieved from buffer: -2147483648
```

P.S.

The reason why I want to store int in a char array is an integer flag needs be set into a binary buffer, from a specified position and takes 4 bytes in the buffer.

Comment: An alternative to the `memcpy()` is `*((int*)buffer) = input ;`

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing integers, you are storing character strings of digit characters.  In the lines:

```
snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "%d", input1);
snprintf(buffer + INT_WIDTH, BUFFER_SIZE - INT_WIDTH, "%d", input2);
```

the second `snprintf()` overwrites the nul terminator of the first string, and places the digits immediately adjacent to the first. `sscanf()` requires whitespece to delimit fields.  In the second version, you have simply run out of buffer space. Why are you surprised - you are trying to write 12 characters but BUFFER_SIZE is 10?

I wonder why you could not just store the integers in an int array?  If you must store numeric strings, why not use a two dimensional array rather messing around with all that buffer index manipulation.

```
char buffer[2][INT_WIDTH] = {{0},{0}} ;
...
snprintf( buffer[0], INT_WIDTH, "%d", input1 ) ;
snprintf( buffer[1], INT_WIDTH, "%d", input2 ) ;
...
sscanf( buffer[0], "%d", &output1 ) ;
sscanf( buffer[1], "%d", &output1 ) ;
```

To store a 32bit signed integer of any length as a string you will need an INT_WIDTH of 12; up to 10 digits, a possible negative sign and the nul terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe what you are trying to do?
Why do you want to store an INT inside a CHAR array?

The Problem is, that depending on your hardware, INT can be bigger in size than CHAR.
You can use sizeof(int) and sizeof(char) to check this.

Normally CHAR will have 8Bit (1Byte) and INT will have 32Bit (4Byte).
So bigger numbers than 255 won't fit inside a CHAR variable!

Comment: Read the code again - he is storing a numeric string in a char buffer not an int in a char.  Moreover this is a comment not an answer.  Post it as a comment.